# Is there a difference between redirect()->route() and route()?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

These two:

```
return redirect()->route('...');

return route('...');
```

seem to do the same thing. Is there a reason to not use the shorter form?

Comment: they don't do the same thing at all ... one returns a redirect response to a route, the other returns a string URL to a route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**route()**

its helper function and it generates the URL to a named route.if you see the source code

```
if (! function_exists('route')) {
    /**
     * Generate the URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $name
     * @param  mixed  $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @return string
     */
    function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
}
```

**redirect()->route()**

Here `redirect()` is helper function to `Redirector class`.

```
if (! function_exists('redirect')) {
    /**
     * Get an instance of the redirector.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $to
     * @param  int  $status
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @param  bool|null  $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
    {
        if (is_null($to)) {
            return app('redirect');
        }

        return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }
}
```

`redirect()->route()` Create a new redirect response to a named route.

```
/**
 * Create a new redirect response to a named route.
 *
 * @param  string  $route
 * @param  mixed  $parameters
 * @param  int  $status
 * @param  array  $headers
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function route($route, $parameters = [], $status = 302, $headers = [])
{
    return $this->to($this->generator->route($route, $parameters), $status, $headers);
}
```

Here if you see the source code then you have an option to set the **status code** and **headers** but in the case of `route()` can only generate the URL to a named route.

For better understanding,if you `dd(redirect()->route('home'));`

[image]

if you `dd(\route('home'));` then its plain url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect()->route('...');
```

it will redirect user to specific route

```
return route('...');
```

will return a specific route ( link )